# TFS 2018 - Can't use Environment.Name within Release

Tags: tfs, devops

When doing a Release and trying to use the variable `Environment.Name` I get the error:

> ##[error]Environment.Name : The term 'Environment.Name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
>       operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
>       again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Release.EnvironmentName`

## Note:

If while in a Build Definition you click on the `variables` tab then you click the link [Predefined Variables](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkid=615899) this will send you to a page that is titled "Build Variables" so if you are like me you might think this page contains all the available variables within TFS pipelines but it doesn't.  You have to click the link titled [release variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops) near the top within the purple note, or edit a Release then click the `variables` tab there.